# Type is always _doc with Searchkick 4.3.1 and ES 7.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

We're using Searchkick 4.3.1 with ElasticSearch 7.4.x and have noticed all models are now indexed with type `_doc`. This is even though Searchkick appears to still be generating a `:_type` properly for the index.

Given:

```rb
class Announcement < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick
end
```

We have the following output:

```
Announcement.searchkick_index.options[:_type].call
=> "announcement"
```

But when we get search results, the hits are coming back with `type: "_doc"`:

```
Announcement.searchkick('test').hits
=> [{"_index"=>"announcements_development_20200527141317316", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"108111", "_score"=>52.14424},
{"_index"=>"announcements_development_20200527141317316", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"90441", "_score"=>47.764935},
{"_index"=>"announcements_development_20200527141317316", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"63721", "_score"=>47.682816},
{"_index"=>"announcements_development_20200527141317316", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"102031", "_score"=>47.682816},
{"_index"=>"announcements_development_20200527141317316", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"19071", "_score"=>46.733723}]
```

Where this really manifests as a problem is when we're performing searches across multiple models. Specifically because these multiple model searches would have different `where` conditions per model and we would scope those conditions as follows:
`where({ _or: [{type: '_announcement', active: true}, {type: '_event', upcoming: true} ])`

Now that `type` is always `'_doc'`, these result sets are always empty. I've also tried explicitly using the `_index` name in the `where` but Searchkick returns the index's alias for the following:

```
Announcement.searchkick_index.name
=> "announcements_development"
```

Is this an issue with Searchkick? Because it seems like still it *should* be setting the `_type` on the index appropriately. The following article (https://www.elastic.co/blog/removal-of-mapping-types-elasticsearch#mapping-type) under the Elasticsearch 7.x removal notes says:

> 7.x indices which don’t have an explicit type will use the dummy type name _doc.

but should that apply here? Seems like Searchkick would still set the type.

Any help would be appreciated. Perhaps there's another way to scope `where` conditions to a specific index when performing multiple model searches?

Comment: I ran into this as well and looked into the code to find the following [line](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/7ce0440ab4f2fdd02a52b2bcf42fb4f90e668667/lib/searchkick/record_data.rb#L42) added in [commit](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/commit/7ce0440ab4f2fdd02a52b2bcf42fb4f90e668667). I'm assuming the `options[:_type].call` still works to cater for older elasticsearch versions. As recommended by the same article you linked, could you add a custom type field? https://www.elastic.co/blog/removal-of-mapping-types-elasticsearch#alternatives